# Shorter way of writing nested PHP for loops

Tags: php, for-loop

Is there any way to write multiple nested loops with a shorter syntax in PHP?

Currently, the nested for loops look like this:

```
for($n = 4; $n <= 5; $n++) {
  for($x = 200; $x <= 4000; $x++) {
    for($y = 0.8*$x; $a <= 0.9*$x; $y++) {
       $result = new Fraction ( $n*$y - $x , $n - 1 );
       // More stuff;
    }
  }
}
```

Can I do something similar to this?

```
do {
    $n = rand(2, 5);
    $x = rand(200, 4000);
    $y = rand((int)(0.8*$x), (int)(0.9*$x));
    $result = new Fraction ( $n*$y - $x , $n - 1 );
} while (!is_allowed($result, $den_limit, true));
```

I know I am using `rand()` but that's because I don't know a how to go over all values in a loop. Is there some way I can replicate the nested loops above using syntax similar to what I wrote at the bottom?

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing?? The first two for loops break each other. The first one loops while $x is less than or equal to 5 then the next loop sets $x to 200 breaking the first loop.

Comment: @Andreas I have corrected the loops. :)

Comment: If you want to loop all combinations of values, you will need to nest the loops. No way around it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Can I do something similar to second part using `range()` instead of `rand()` and something like that?

Comment: You still would be looping through them.